# Unable to run PIP commands despite it claiming to be installed

Tags: python, pip

Every time I try to use pip to install a new package, I get the message `command not found: pip`. Therefore, I go about the process of installing pip, and I follow the process in pip's documentation to check if it has been installed. I run `python3 --version` which gives me `Python 3.8.2`. Then I run `python3 -m pip --version` and this gives me `pip 22.0.4 from /Users/corgangoodrow/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

I've been thinking that maybe the path of the python3 that my computer is running is not connected to the pip that I have downloaded. When I run `which python3` I get `/usr/bin/python3` Could someone provide some insight into what is going on?

Comment: `python3 -m pip show --files pip` ; note the `bin/` directory and add it to `$PATH`.

Comment: Most probably the directory is `/Users/corgangoodrow/Library/Python/3.8/bin/`